# Beautiful Soup Get Attribute Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Getting an error : `"linkdetail = link.get('href') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"` in the following script.

If I run it with the commented lines instead of the last two it grabs the correct element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import sys

import os.path

for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(i))
    link_list = []
    soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8')
    link = soup.find(class_="attribute-url")
    ## link_list.append(link)
    ## print link_list
    linkdetail = link.get('href')
    print linkdetail
```

Any help appreciated, I'm stuck.

Comment: Evidently it's not finding an element with class `attribute-url`. Show us the input file with which your program is having problems.

Comment: @MattBall - If I just print the variable 'link' I get the following :`<div class="attribute-url">
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>` Which is correct, but I'm attempting to grab only the URL.

Comment: `link` is `None`Type, so I'd guess that this is happening on a different pass through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this -

```
    links = soup.findAll('a')
    for link in links:
        linkdetail = link.get('href')
        print linkdetail
```

Comment: Thanks @vaibhav, I added some details above.

Comment: This is actually closest to what I went with. Which was : 


`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import sys

import os.path

for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(i))
    link_list = []
    soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8')
    ## link = soup.find(class_="attribute-url")
    attrul = soup.select(".attribute-url > a")
    for all in attrul:
        linkclean =  all.get('href')
        print linkclean`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
    links = soup.findAll(class_="attribute-url")
    for link in links:
        print link.text
```

Comment: Thanks @rydallcooper, I added some details above.